# Programmatic Routing in SwiftUI for TabView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm working on a SwiftUI application that follows a navigation pattern similar to Instagram, with a TabView at the root and complex navigation paths starting from different tabs. I've set up my navigation based on a method described in a [blog post about creating a better TabView](https://notificare.com/blog/2022/11/25/a-better-tabview-in-swiftui/) in SwiftUI, but I'm running into issues with more complex navigation flows.

**The Problem:**

My app has two main navigation flows starting from FeedsView and ProfileView, both of which are part of the TabView. The navigation flow is as follows:

```
FeedsView -> FeedDetailsView -> EditFeedView
ProfileView -> FeedDetailsView -> EditFeedView
```

However, when navigating from ProfileView, the navigation to EditFeedView doesn't work as expected. Here's the simplified DetailsView code:

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Details")
            NavigationLink(value: FeedNavDestination.edit) {
                Text("Open Edit screen")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("Details")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

FeedNavDestination.edit doesn't trigger navigation when coming from ProfileView.

Here's an overview of my TabView setup:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var appState = AppState()

    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                TabView(selection: createTabViewBinding(scrollViewProxy: proxy)) {
                    FeedView()
                        .tag(ContentViewTab.home)
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Home", systemImage: "house.fill")
                        }
                    
                    SearchView()
                        .tag(ContentViewTab.settings)
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Search", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                        }
                    
                    ProfileView()
                        .tag(ContentViewTab.profile)
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Profile", systemImage: "person")
                        }
                    
                    
                }
            
        }
        .environmentObject(appState)
    }
    private func createTabViewBinding(scrollViewProxy: ScrollViewProxy) -> Binding<ContentViewTab> {
            Binding<ContentViewTab>(
                get: { appState.selectedTab },
                set: { selectedTab in
                    if selectedTab == appState.selectedTab {
                        switch selectedTab {
                        case .home:
                            if appState.feedNavigation.isEmpty {
                               
                            } else {
                                withAnimation {
                                    appState.feedNavigation = []
                                }
                            }
                        case .settings:
                            if appState.searchNavigation.isEmpty {
                            
                            } else {
                                withAnimation {
                                    appState.searchNavigation = []
                                }
                            }
                        case .profile:
                            print("profile")
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
                    appState.selectedTab = selectedTab
                }
            )
        }
}
```

And the navigation model:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTab: ContentViewTab = .home
    
    @Published var feedNavigation: [FeedNavDestination] = []
    @Published var searchNavigation: [SearchNavDestination] = []
    @Published var profileNavigation: [ProfileNavDestination] = []
}

enum AppNavDestination {
    case homeDetails
    case searchDetails
    case edit
    
    // Add other destinations as needed
}

enum ContentViewTab {
    case home
    case profile
    case settings
}

enum FeedNavDestination {
    case details
    case edit
}

enum SearchNavDestination {
    case details
    case edit
}
enum ProfileNavDestination {
    case settings
}
```

**Additional Issue:**

Navigating to SearchView from any other tab results in non-functional navigation links because it contains a NavigationStack, similar to the other views.
Questions:

- How can I ensure that navigation to EditFeedView works correctly from both FeedsView and ProfileView?
- How can I address the issue where navigation stops working when switching tabs that contain their own NavigationStack?

I'm looking for guidance or solutions to these navigation challenges in a SwiftUI app with a structure similar to Instagram's navigation pattern. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Switching" tabs goes against Apple's HIG, all tabs in a tab bar should be mutually exclusive. There is no "easy" answer because Apple does not want this type of navigation to happen

Comment: But the Instagram and facebook have this kind of navigation.

Comment: They don't use SwiftUI, SwiftUI is meant for rapid development with maximum compatibility. You can create your own custom view any time. It is possible to do it just isn't built in.